# Found a lizard in my car, I have not driven it for 20 or more days

Tags: air-intake

I went on a vacation for three weeks. When I came back and opened my car, I found a lizard in the car. I have had the air re-circulating knob set to ON.

I am still guessing how this lizard entered my car?

Comment: I have lizards in in car too. They're gigantic, come in the liquid form, hundred millions years old - I call it gas.   :)

Answer (score 6):

Two things come to mind here:

- First, cars are a sieve. There are more holes in them than you can shake a stick at. Lizards are very *pliable* creatures and can fit through any of these small openings if it fits their needs.
- Second, the lizard may have been in your car since the last time you were in your car. You never know.

Comment: Its possible. But still what should be done to avoid such incidents?

Comment: @Palak.Maheria - Something has invited the lizard to come into your car. The best bet is to make it uninviting for them. Ensure your car is clean. You can also try dryer sheets. This works for rodents as I guess they don't like the smell (or something). I'm not sure if it would work for lizards, but having a couple of dryer sheets under the car seats is not a bad thing. Will help keep the car deodorized. Beyond that, I'm not sure what you could do. I don't know if lizards are a big deal for you, either. As in, are there tons of them in your area.

Comment: @Palak.Maheria Drive the car at least once a week. Lizards dont like thier house moving about the city ..